# ETHREAD Structure and CreateThread "dwCreationFlags"

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm working on a function to extract information about a thread and would like to know more specifically when calling the CreateThread function, the created thread insert "dwCreationFlags" parameter somewhere in ETHREAD structure

Comment: There's no language involved here at all. This is a pure Win32 question. Admittedly it is a little hard to understand what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 3):

Since these flags only affect thread *creation*, there is no need to keep them once the thread exists. So no, they are not kept in the `ETHREAD`.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I'm trying to find a place in ETHREAD structure that indicate whether a thread was created suspended.

Comment: already tried "state, suspendcount, waitreason" but these are about the current state of the thread.

Comment: I messed up on this response, I meant that would like to get this information from somewhere in the process!

Comment: Once the thread is created, you can't tell if it was created suspended and was resumed later, or the other way around. Just give up.